# How can I enable the width and height in view (size inspector) xcode 11?

Tags: swift, xcode, uistackview, xcode11

Very basic question. How can I enable the width and height in view (size inspector) xcode 11?
As you can see below in screenshot, the height is grayed out. I have the same issue in other stack views and the Image view is also have similar issue. The first Stack view is not grayed out but I still cannot change it (It revert the change automatically )

[image]

Update: Currenty I am using a workaround . I change the intrinsic  Size to place holder and manually add the numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set the frame of an view that's inside a stack view. If you want an arranged subview (of a stack view) to have a width or a height, you need to use an autolayout constraint. Click the "Add New Constraint" button at the bottom of that window, then check "width" and/or "height".